# Using logical operators on integers in C

Tags: c, integer, logical-operators, short-circuiting, logical-or

> Logical OR and Logical AND operator on integers in C

Can you explain me why the values of a,b,c are 11,10,1 respectively.
Why the value of b remains same as 10?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    a=b=c=10;
    c = a++ || ++b && ++c;
    printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at the order of operations.  The logical AND operator `&&` has higher precedence than the logcial OR operator `||`, so the expression parses as follows:

```
c = a++ || (++b && ++c);
```

Next, both `||` and `&&` are short circut operators.  This means that the left has side is evaluated first, and if the result can be determined solely from that then the right hand side is not evaluated.

So `a` starts out with the value 10.  `a++` evaluates to the current value (10) while incrementing `a` as a side effect.  This means the value 10 is the left hand side of `||`.  Because this is a non-zero value, the value of the entire expression is 1 and the right hand side `++b && ++c` is not evaluated.  Then this result is assigned to 1.

So the end result is `a` is incremented to 11, `c` is assigned 1 because that is the value of the `||` expression, and `b` is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
c = a++ || ++b && ++c;
```

can be equivalently rewritten like

```
c = ( a++ ) || ( ++b && ++c );
```

As the expression a++ is not equal to 0 then the second sub-expression `( ++b && ++c )` is not evaluated.

The value of the logical operator || and && is either 1 (true) or 0.

From the C Standard (6.5.14 Logical OR operator)

> 3 The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare
>   unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

and

> 4 Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. **If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated**.

So `c` gets the value `1` and `a` was increased.

Comment: As && has higher precedence than ||. So the expression should be evaluated as c = ( a++ || ++b ) && ( ++c ) ; and the b value should increase! don't you think?

Comment: @nish_13 No,. The operators are evaluated from the left to the right. I used parentheses for the expression  in my answer to show how it is evaluated.

Comment: @nish_13 Consider for example expression a + b * c. This expression is equivalent to a + ( b * c ) not to ( a + b ) * c. However it does not mean that b * c evaluates first. As for the logical operator OR then if the first operand evaluates to true the second operand does not evaluate.

Comment: yes, now i got it 2*3+1 is expressed as (2*3)+1 because * has higher precedence than + and the higher precedence operator is enclosed within the parenthesis. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Expanding, a little bit, on the other answers, you have to understand what your statement is actually doing.

```
a=b=c=10;
c = a++ || ++b && ++c;
```

The logical operators take, naturally, boolean operands, so your statement is (implicitly):

```
c = ( a++ != 0 ) || ( ++b != 0 ) && ( ++c != 0 );
```

Note, interestingly, that the order of precedence places the AND operator higher than the OR operator - which implies that `++b` **should** be executed.

However, given the short-circuit operation of logical-OR, the first term is known to be `true` therefore `c = 1 (ie true)`.

--

Regular readers will, of course, expect me to add a MISRA slant to my answer...

MISRA C:2012 Rule 13.5 covers this exact scenario... it states that *The right hand operand of a logical `&&` or `||` operator shall not contain persistent side effects*

So a MISRA Compliant version of your code would be:

```
a=b=c=10;

a++;
b++;
c++;  // This is actually *dead code*

c = a || ( b && c );

printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
```